# 3 arrays in d3.js - how to call other arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have 3 arrays in d3.js. These are made up of team names, % win record, and team colours.

Example:

```
var TeamArray = ["Yankees",  "Rays", "RedSox", "Jays","Orioles", "Twin", "Indians", "WhiteSox", "Detroit", "Royals", "Astros", "Rangers", "A's", "Angels","Mariners"];
var WinPercArray = [653, 609, 540, 400, 300, 667, 521, 458, 383, 347, 660, 511, 500, 458, 442];
var Colours = ["#003087", "#092C5C", "#BD3039", "#134A8E", "#DF4601", "#002B5C", "#0C2340", "#C4CED4", "#FA4616", "#BD9B60", "#EB6E1F", "#C0111F", "#003831", "#003263", "#005C5C"];
```

When I create the svg container, I use the win percentage array, as I need to draw the charts with it. That is done.

However, I need to import the second array, in order to change the colours of the chart to correspond with the team colours.

```
let svgContainer = d3.select("#baseball").append("svg")
    .attr("height",800)
    .attr("width",800);

var myRectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(WinPercArray)         

myRectangle.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return 45 + (i * 50);
    })

    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return 800 - d;
    })

    .attr("width", 45)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d;
    })

    .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
        if (d < 350) {return "red";}
        else if (d < 400) {return "tomato";}
        else if (d < 450) {return "orange";}
        else if (d < 500) {return "mediumseagreen";}
        else if (d < 550) {return "blue";}
        else {return "purple";}
    })
```

How do I do this?

Comment: When you say *"the color of the chart"* do you mean the color of each individual rectangle?

Comment: Yes.  May have worded it badly due to tiredness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind selection (nicely) to single array, and you'll have to group your data as such. D3 offers array utilities, and one of them is zip (https://github.com/d3/d3-array#zip), which groups given arrays' elements by index (if you think of your data as a table, it changes from arrays of rows into arrays of columns).

Once you have your data grouped, it's just a matter of choosing right attribute (index) from bound data to the element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var TeamArray = ["Yankees", "Rays", "RedSox", "Jays", "Orioles", "Twin", "Indians", "WhiteSox", "Detroit", "Royals", "Astros", "Rangers", "A's", "Angels", "Mariners"];
    var WinPercArray = [653, 609, 540, 400, 300, 667, 521, 458, 383, 347, 660, 511, 500, 458, 442];
    var Colours = ["#003087", "#092C5C", "#BD3039", "#134A8E", "#DF4601", "#002B5C", "#0C2340", "#C4CED4", "#FA4616", "#BD9B60", "#EB6E1F", "#C0111F", "#003831", "#003263", "#005C5C"];

    let svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("height", 800)
      .attr("width", 800);

    var myRectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(d3.zip(TeamArray, WinPercArray, Colours))

    myRectangle.enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return 45 + (i * 50);
      })

      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return 800 - d[1];
      })

      .attr("width", 45)
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })

      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return d[2];
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/d3/d3-scale . They give succinct way of transforming your logical data (eg percentages [0; 100]) to graphical data (eg height [0; 800]) instead of calculating it yourself like you do it here (WinPercArray) and risking to having to redo it if e.g. you want to change chart size

Comment: thanks for the help on the scales and colours. Had not seen that method before.